# Java/Android: Method with Full Project Scope

Tags: java, android

I have a method that I've created that I would like to be able to use anywhere, but I don't know what the best practice is for giving access to that method throughout the project. Do I just create a .java file with a public method and that will give access throughout? Will I need to declare it anywhere (somewhere in the manifest?)?

I'm sure this has been asked, but I am not returning anything useful on my google searches. I am not good enough at googling for Android, yet! Sorry for adding to the duplicates, if I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.  The simplest is a `public static` method.

```
public class MyClass {
  public static MyReturnType myMethod(MyArgumentType input) {
    // my code here
  }
}
```

You will now be able to call this like:

```
MyClass.myMethod(arg);
```

Comment: i think `Application class` is good place for these types of methods instead of static

Comment: `Application` class? Where is that in the project?

Answer (score 1):

Use static methods. As for me, if I want to store just methods in the same place I create a new class and all of the methods are static. For example.

```
public static int parseInt(String str)
{
    try
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

If it's just do anything and doesn't require to save state in the class, this is the best solution.

Comment: Won't I run into issues with calling static methods from non-static methods?

Comment: Nope.  THe issue is with calling non-static methods without an instance.

Comment: Calling static methods inside non-static method is legal however, calling non-static methods inside static methods will give you a compile time error.

Comment: Okay. So, when its going backwards (without an instance, since its the equivalent to an Objective-C class method), thats when its an issue because it can't pass a self parameter. Thank you!

Comment: Calling non-static methods within statics is fine, as long as you supply an instance.  Otherwise main (which is static) could never get to non-static code.

Comment: I think the reason behind that, how would a class method or static method call a non instantiated object method. Static methods exist before the instance itself.

Comment: @MelNicholson How can you supply an instance?

Comment: MyObject myInstance = new MyObject(). there' you've created an instance of MyObject, but I think that's a difference question, not related to this question.

Comment: @KyelJmD I meant, how can you supply the instance to a non-static method. With my static method, it may need to call a non-static method at some point.

Comment: wait, I'll post it in my answer.

Comment: You have to call your static method like MyObject.myMethod();

Comment: @KyelJmD Oh. So, its not that you pass the instance, but rather you use the instance to call the method, which implicitly passes self. Thank you!

Comment: @RileyE I've posted my answer.

Comment: @KyelJmD Okay, but it doesn't include how to call back from the static method. I think for the sake of the question, the simpler answer is the best option. Thank you for the answer, though!

Comment: @RileyE No problem. just posted my answer just in case other people might find it helpful, specially for newbies, Cheers!

Comment: @KyelJmD Thank you for that! I appreaciate it. I'm sure other people will find use from each answer.

Comment: Alright! Cheers, just be sure to select what is the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of a static method.

```
public class Messages {
    public static String mySpecialFinalMessage(){
        return "Hello Stackoverflow";
    }
}
```

You no longer need to create an Instance of `Messages` to call `mySpecialFinalMessage()` because it is a static. The best practice to call a static method is in this format `CLASSNAME.STATICMETHODNAME();`

So in our example,

```
Messages.mySpecialFinalMessage()
```

Please Note that you calling static methods inside non-static method is legal however, calling non-static methods inside static methods will give you a compile time error.

this is legal

```
public class MyMessage {

    public String getMessage(){
        return Messages.mySpecialFinalMessage();
    }
}
```

Take note taht Messages.mySpecialFinalMessage() is that static method. Also, Notice that we did not create an instance of Messages to call mySpecialFinalMessage(), rather we've just called it directly by `CLASSNAME.STATICMETHODNAME`

Comment: Your example of an illegal call is actually legal as written.  The compile time error would occur when you make a call like MyClass.myNonStaticMethod( ).  The call myObject.myNonStaticMethod( ) is allowed, though there will be an NPE if myObject has not been initialized to an instance.

Comment: It's legal, unless there's an instance of that object, looks like I missed to explain that.